# posting xml to a rest api with php

Tags: php, xml, api, rest, post

I really hope someone can help me along with this one...

I need to do an xml POST to RESTful API using php, but I have absolutely no clue where to start.

I can build the xml, but how do I post the it? I cant use cURL library.

Comment: Why can't you use cURL? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478077/php4-http-post-without-curl) may help.

Comment: I need this script to run on a number of servers, some of which may not have the Library, so I cant rely on it.

Comment: @JamWaffles ok, turns out I can use cURL. I have put something together, but now I am stuck separating the http returned headers and the xml return.

Comment: `code`$ch = curl_init($this->ApiUrl . $method ."/");
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);// header will be part of output
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Comment: how would I separate the two? I need this to check if I got errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents(). `allow_url_fopen` must be set on php.ini.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array(
    'method' => 'POST'
    'content' => $myXMLBody
)));
$returnData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/restfulapi', false, $context);
```

This is possible because PHP abstracts stream manipulation with his own wrappers. Setting a context to stream manipulation functions (like file_get_contents()) allows you to configure how PHP handles it.

There are more parameters than just `method` and `content`. You can set request headers, proxies, handle timeouts and everything. Please refer to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Comment: Thx you for this solution. This have help me to call a REST API which using XML without Guzzle (old project).

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem a couple of days ago and finaly someone came up with this solution, but do not use $this->_request to get the post request as it doesn't work with xml, not at least in my case.

```
$service_url1 = 'http://localhost/restTest/respond/';
$curl1 = curl_init($service_url1);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$arr=array("key"=>$xml);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$arr);
echo $curl1_response = curl_exec($curl1);

curl_close($curl1);
```